# Do not see MessageBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, messagebox

Why do I not see the MessageBox with exception details when I run my program by executing exe fine in bin debug folder?

I do see the exception when I debug (run) the program from Visual Studio.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show(
            string.Format("There were unhandeled exceptions. Would you like to continue using this program?"),
            "Fatal Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
            MessageBoxIcon.Error) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
                Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

***Edit***
Here is the code that generates the exception:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int num = 1;
    num = num / (num - num);
}
```

Comment: Strange, when I test this, I do see the messagebox....

Comment: "There were unhandeled exceptions. Yes/No?" Impending daily WTF if ever I saw one...

Comment: The program will exit in your example even if you answer no. What are you trying to accomplish? If you want to handle unhandled exceptions and not necessarily exit the program, there's other ways to do this. Also, are the exceptions thrown from a thread (BackgroundWorker, BeginInvoke, Thread, Task, etc.)?

Comment: @Joachim did you try throwing an exception before the call to Application.Run?

Comment: Can you post the code that throws the exception, and how you call that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line:

```
try 
{
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException);
    ...
```

Apparently the default is different when debugging. I don't know the details about that.

Also note that your `if(...) Application.Exit();` is not really useful here, and it shouldn't.
Don't try to restart or anything.

Comment: +1, this is correct.  The message loop behaves differently when the debugger is attached.  Makes it easy to debug exceptions.